# How to customize form validation messages

Tags: django, forms, validation, message

I am currently using the forms in django.contrib.auth to change a user password, but i would like to customize the validation messages without editing the django/contrib/auth/forms.py file

Anyone got any pointers? Would help me a lot!

Comment: Please don't start your titles with "Django: "  We know you're asking a question about Django.  Its the lead tag on your question.  people who are watching the django tag will see your question as highlighted in the list of questions.  People who watch the django RSS feed will see your question in their reader.  Prefacing your titles with a tag does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Updated according to the comment -  the same principle still applies: subclass the form and override.)

Subclass the form and override the clean method for the particular field:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordChangeForm

class MyPasswordChangeForm(PasswordChangeForm):
    def clean_old_password(self):
        try:
            return super(MyPasswordChangeForm, self).clean_old_password():
        except forms.ValidationError:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Booh, the password was not correct!")
```

... then use `MyPasswordChangeForm` instead of PasswordChangeForm in your views.

Comment: actually i was referring to this kind of messages (when the validation fails) e.g.:
    line 197 in forms.py from contrib auth: raise forms.ValidationError(_("Your old password was entered incorrectly. Please enter it again."))

Comment: great! thats exactly what I needed. one more thing, i wanna understand this what does super() do? i read about it a bit but i couldnt understand it, what does it do in this example ? thanks again!

Comment: It calls the "super"/"parent" method. MyPasswordChangeForm inherits from PasswordChangeForm. super(MyPasswordChangeForm, self) gives an instance of PasswordChangeForm with the current data. What happends is that PasswordChangeForm.clean_old_password is called, the validation error is caught if thrown, and a custom error is raised instead.